# Is putting !important on @font-face is valid?

Tags: css, font-face

I have a problem that I want the user to force use the web font instead of the font installed on his computer because they both have slightly different formatting. I looked up `!important` but I am not sure and when I tried it I am not getting that it is working or not. Anyone please here can tell me how to use `!important` on `@font-face`? Is it valid or not?

Comment: If you use your custom font at the beginning of the `font-face` rule it will use that font, no need for the important.

Comment: read font-face rules from this links : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Honestly, never use `!important`. It's horrible,

Comment: Because it ruins the cascade of the CSS, and can cause lots of problems down the road. http://codeumbra.eu/why-you-should-use-important-as-a-last-resort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this:

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'custom-font';
    src: url('custom-font.eot');
    src: url('custom-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('custom-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('custom-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('custom-font.svg#custom') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}



p { font-family: 'custom-font', Arial, sans-serif;  }
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Your text here</p>
```